# Matlab linear correlation matrix in copularnd (copula random number) function

Tags: matlab, random, statistics, correlation

Consider we have 4 vectors, `V1`,`V2`,`nf1` and `nf2`. We need to generate `n=8736` random numbers that each pair of `(V1,V2)` , `(V1,nf1)`, `(V2,nf2)` and `(nf1,nf2)` to be correlate as follow:

```
Rvv=0.6 for (V1,V2)
Rvn=0.5 for (V1,nf1) and (V2,nf2)
Rnn=0 for (nf1,nf2)
```

(It's not important what correlation of `(V1,nf2)` and `(V2, nf1)` is). Now we use copula to generate correlated random numbers in MATLAB:

```
    Rvv=0.6;
    Rvn=0.5;
    Rnn=0;
    n = 8736;

            %V1     V2     nf1      nf2
    Rho =   [1      Rvv     Rvn     0  ;    %V1
            Rvv      1       0      Rvn;    %V2
            Rvn     0       1       Rnn;    %nf1
            0       Rvn     Rnn     1 ];    %nf2

    Random_no = copularnd('Gaussian',Rho,n);
```

It's all OK when `Rvv` is `0.6`, and `Random_no` will be a `8736 by 4` matrix, that each pair of columns are correlated as we specified by `Rho` Matrix. BUT when `Rvv=0.9`, MATLAB returns error as follow:

```
Error using mvnrnd
SIGMA must be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.
Error in copularnd 
u = normcdf(mvnrnd(zeros(1,d),Rho,n));
```

I can't understand what the problem is and how can I really generate correlated random numbers using copula. I'll really appreciate if anyone can help me through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer about theory, but got this in code of `copularnd`:

```
case 'gaussian'
    Rho = varargin{1};
    n = varargin{2};
    d = size(Rho,1);
    if isscalar(Rho)
        if ~(-1 < Rho && Rho < 1)
            error(message('stats:copularnd:BadScalarCorrelation'));
        end
        Rho = [1 Rho; Rho 1];
        d = 2;
    elseif any(diag(Rho) ~= 1)
        error(message('stats:copularnd:BadCorrelationMatrix'));
    end
    % MVNRND will check that Rho is square, symmetric, and positive semi-definite.
    u = normcdf(mvnrnd(zeros(1,d),Rho,n));
```

Because of there no any information about it in help, I think it must be clearly for people who knows what copula is :) but is not for me

There are a lot of ways to generate positive semi-definite matrices: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/163489